# XSL Transform cannot invoke user defined Java Method

Tags: java, xalan, xslt

I have the following XSL which defines a namespace for my Java Class. In a nutshell I'm trying to point to a different resource bundle depending upon a value in my XML file (I know Resource Bundles are really for internationalization but why re-create the wheel?):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
                xmlns:pf="my.package.common.PropertiesFinder">

    <xsl:variable name="compType" select="//comp_type"/>
    <xsl:variable name="props" select="pf:getPropsFile($compType)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="DEF6Resources" select="java:util.ResourceBundle.getBundle($props)"/>
```

When the transform runs I get the following error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function, could not find method org.apache.xml.utils.NodeVector.getProps([ExpressionContext,])

Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening please. It's clearly something to do with my classpath/loader but I'm not sure what to do...

Many thanks in advance.

Anna

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a "classnotfoundexception" tag, but the body contains `NoSuchMethodException` instead.

Comment: Where is the jar file that contains `org.apache.xml.utils.NodeVector.getProps()`? What is the current classpath as far as you know? How are you passing the classpath to the XSLT processor (which I assume is Xalan)? I'm shooting in the dark, but presumably the answers to those q's will help us and you narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your namespace definition.

```
xmlns:pf="my.package.common.PropertiesFinder"
```

When you are defining a namespace for a Java class, you have to prepend it with the `java:` prefix.

```
xmlns:pf="java:my.package.common.PropertiesFinder"
```

Also, the method invoked (`getPropsFile`) must be declared as `static`.

And, I think that at this block of code:

```
<xsl:variable name="DEF6Resources" select="java:util.ResourceBundle.getBundle($props)"/>
```

You are missing the java root package:

```
<xsl:variable name="DEF6Resources" select="java:java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle($props)"/>
```

(I'm not sure of this last, maybe the Xalan parser prepends it for some cases?)

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem.

Finally I found  that Xalan is unable to load classes with static blocks or static variables, or something like that.
Maybe `PropertiesFinder` or `ResourceBundle` use static blocks internally.
The error message was really misleading...